# Python Assertion for ValueError

Tags: python, assert, valueerror

Is there a way to use `assert` in pure Python to test for a ValueError?

E.g. something like:

```
def try_me():
    raise ValueError("No way Jose")

assert try_me() is ValueError
```

Comment: I'm curious what your intended use-case is. Are you - for example - doing this as part of a unit test, testing some method raises a particular type of error when called in a certain way? If so, most test frameworks have ways of doing this using the framework (but the how will depend on the framework you use).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [unittest.TestCase.assertRaises](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises) from the unittest module. Checking if the `try_me` function raises `ValueError` looks like this:

```
import unittest


def try_me():
    raise ValueError("No way Jose")


class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_if_throws_exception(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, try_me)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`assert`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement) evaluates only [`expressions`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-expression).

But you can do:

```
def catch_exception(method):
    try:
        method()
    except Exception as e:
        return e.__class__


def try_me():
    raise ValueError("No way Jose")


assert catch_exception(try_me) is ValueError  # okay
assert catch_exception(try_me) is IndexError  # fails
```

Answer (score 0):

`pytest` is a good module to learn for unit testing your code and is very simple for this type of testing.  Try this instead:

```
import pytest
    
with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        try_me()
```